# when i fetch image from camera that time crash my application in Redmi note 3

Tags: android

Sometimes fetch the image from a camera that time crash my application. My log cat error is shown here.

```
10-10 09:35:25.173 470-470/? E/mm-camera-isp2: isp_port_check_caps_unreserve:820 ide 1000f port 0xab1d1800 10-10 09:35:25.174 470-470/? E/mm-camera-CORE: af_port_event:5197  af_port_event: Received AF port event type: 2, dir: 1
    af_port_handle_module_event:3394  af_port_handle_module_event: Handle AF module event of type: 112
    af_port_handle_module_event:3656  af_port_handle_module_event: Default. no action!
    af_port_event:5247  af_port_event: X rc: 1 10-10 09:35:25.178 470-470/? E/mm-camera: mct: mct_pipeline_stop_stream_internal stream unmap_parm failed 10-10 09:35:25.179 470-6766/? E/mm-camera-isp2: isp_module_stop_session:456 session id 1 10-10 09:35:25.182 470-6768/? E/mm-camera-CORE: af_module_stop_session:186  af_module_stop_session: AF Module - stop session 10-10 09:35:25.183 470-6768/? E/mm-camera-CORE: af_module_stop_session:202  af_module_stop_session: Remove AF port from the list!
    af_module_stop_session:205  af_module_stop_session: Deinit AF port 10-10 09:35:25.185 470-6578/? E/mm-camera: :cpp_hardware_set_clock:356 Set clock 160000000 BW abg 0 BW inst 0 10-10 09:35:25.186 470-6770/? E/mm-camera-pp: [INFO] base_module_stop_session:98, E, session=1 10-10 09:35:25.187 470-6770/? E/mm-camera-eztune: [INFO] eztune_module_stop_session:49, E, session=1 10-10 09:35:25.187 470-6771/? E/mm-camera: module_faceproc_stop_session:1812] session cnt 1 10-10 09:35:25.192 470-6768/? E/mm-camera-CORE: af_single_destroy:70 af_single destroy success!
    af_core_deinit:508   E
    af_module_stop_session:208  af_module_stop_session: Destroy AF port 10-10 09:35:25.194 470-6768/? E/mm-camera-CORE: gyro_port_deinit:1386  gyro_port_deinit: Error in android Deinit
```

Comment: Can you please add code how you are trying to fetch image exactly? and post proper error log because this log cat does not display proper crash reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, I was also facing this problem in redmi devices :

```
      public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```